# Sending OutPut to two files from an array and a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, fstream

What am I doing wrong here? When I send this I am getting totally blank files? Do I need to re-work the array or is the function not actually sending anything to the files? This is homework so helpful tips would be great. I am very confused here so help is much needed.

```
Main- #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include "Payroll.h"
using namespace std;


const int NUM_EMPLOYEE = 75;

int main()
{
    int dependents;
    double payrate;
    string name;
    double hours;
    ifstream fin;
    int count = 0;
    Payroll employeeArray[NUM_EMPLOYEE];
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("employeeData.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening data file\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while(fin >> payrate >> dependents)
        {
            getline(fin, name);
            employeeArray[count].setWage(payrate);
            employeeArray[count].setDependents(dependents);
            employeeArray[count].setName(name);
            cout << "How many hours has" << name << " worked? ";
                cin >> hours;
                employeeArray[count].setHours(hours);
            count++;
        }

    }
    fout.open("payrollDetails.txt");
    fout << " Name              Hours  Regular  Overtime  Gross    Taxes    Net" << endl;  // heading for file
    fout.close();
    fout.open("checkInfo.txt");
    fout << "Net Pay    Name";   // heading for file two
    fout.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        employeeArray[i].printPayDetails(fout << endl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Print Function-

```
void Payroll::printPayDetails(ostream& out)
{
    double normPay = getNormPay();
    double overTime = getOverPay();
    double grossPay = getGrossPay();
    double taxAmount = getTaxRate();
    double netPay = computePay();
    const int SIZE = 9;
    ofstream fout;

    fout.open("payrollDetails.txt");
    out << setw(19) << left << name << fixed << setprecision(2) << right << setw(5) << hours  << setw(SIZE)  << normPay << setw(SIZE) << overTime ;
    out << setw(SIZE) << grossPay << setw(SIZE) << taxAmount <<setw(SIZE) << netPay;
    fout.close();

    fout.open("checkInfo.txt");
    out << netPay << "        " << name;
    fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you aren't clearing the leading newline in the stream:

```
while (fin >> payrate >> dependents)
{
    getline(fin, name);
```

After performing the extraction in the while loop, a newline is left in the stream. `std::getline()` will stop input when it sees that newline, so you have to get rid of it by calling `ignore()`:

```
fin.ignore();
getline(fin, name);
```

Since `ignore()` returns a reference to the stream, you can even use it inside the parameter:

```
getline(fin.ignore(), name);
```

But even more idiomatic is to use `std::ws`, a manipulator that discards all leading whitespace:

```
getline(fin >> ws, name);
```

You also need to put it inside the `if` statement to check if it succeeded:

```
while (fin >> payrate >> dependents && getline(fin >> ws, name))
{
    // ...
```